# How is map searching for value at a given key

Tags: c++, stl

When I access a value in std::map at a given key, does the map search for this value linearly by checking each key-value pair if the key match or does it access the requested value directly?

Comment: An `std::map` would be implemented as a tree. It would search the tree using the comparator to know where to look, using the key.

Comment: see also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. It will have to search through an index to find the value, but it will do that in a way, that is much more efficient than a linear search.

Typically, this is implemented using a [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) and search time will be logarithmic to the number of elements in the map.